# Why doesn't a BFS guarantee a minimal cost path in this case?

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am solving a question on LeetCode:

> Given a matrix consists of 0 and 1, find the distance of the nearest 0 for each cell.  The distance between two adjacent cells is 1 *(important point)*.
>   
>   If input:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [1,1,1]]
```

> then output:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [1,2,1]]
```

The code that *I* wrote adds all the `0`s' locations into a queue and carries out a BFS from each such location in the queue.  Unfortunately it times out.

The highly upvoted solution given is like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[][] updateMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int m = matrix.length;
        int n = matrix[0].length;

        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    queue.offer(new int[] {i, j});
                }
                else {
                    matrix[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
            }
        }

        int[][] dirs = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            int[] cell = queue.poll();
            for (int[] d : dirs) {
                int r = cell[0] + d[0];
                int c = cell[1] + d[1];
                if (r < 0 || r >= m || c < 0 || c >= n || 
                    matrix[r][c] <= matrix[cell[0]][cell[1]] + 1) continue;
                queue.add(new int[] {r, c});
                matrix[r][c] = matrix[cell[0]][cell[1]] + 1;
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }
}
```

While I do more-or-less understand how it works, I had the following question:

Why do we have to check if `matrix[r][c] <= matrix[cell[0]][cell[1]] + 1` - doesn't a BFS guarantee that *if the edge costs are equal, then the path it found to a particular node is the shortest*?  Why do we have to check it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `matrix[r][c]` will be reached by the BFS algorithm only once. In fact, in this problem it *will* be reached multiple times. The guarantee you're talking about is *only* in force when `matrix[r][c]` is reached for the first time.

So, an alternative solution would be to keep another matrix of `Boolean` values marking whether each cell has been visited or not, and replace the check you mention with `!visited[r][c]`. However, keeping the extra matrix would require extra memory - that's the reason to prefer the current approach.

Answer (score 2):

This check is performed to ensure that we do not continue processing a path when it will not give a better result.

Your BFS solution is fine, but not efficient enough. By aborting early, you ensure that you do not perform useless operations and thus will not time out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be easily solved in **Nlog(N)**, where N is the total number of cells in the matrix, using **Dijkstra's Algorithm**. 
The only change that you need to make is, instead of one destination, you will **consider all 0's as the destination**. 
So the initial distance of all the 0's will be zero. Then you can simply proceed with Dijkstra.

**Update:** Solution posted by you is better as its time complexity is **O(N)**.

Comment: How does it answer my question - _doesn't a BFS guarantee that if the edge costs are equal, then the path it found to a particular node is the shortest? Why do we have to check it then?_?!

Comment: @J.Doe This is the best possible solution. Even the solution that you posted is doing something similar.

Comment: I'll try to solve it by Dijkstra's algo, too.  Thanks. :)